# Property of solutions of uniformly elliptic PDE, true?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive solution in $\mathbb{H}^1$ of an uniformly elliptic PDE in an open cube of side lenght 4 centered at the origin.
Is it true that there exists a constant $C$ dependent only on ellipticity and the dimension of the space such that 
$$\left(Meas(Q(3))^{-1}\int_{Q(3)} u^p dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} 
\leq  C \left((Meas(Q(2))^{-1}\int_{Q(2)} u^q dx \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

Where $0< q< 1 < p$

any idea?

I am trying to prove this but am not entirely convinced that it is true!

Comment: Is $\mathbb{H}^1$ the standard Sobolev Space?

Comment: yes!

This question is related to a step in Moser's proof of Harnak's inequality, I think I managed to modify it so that I can avoid proving this, but it would still be interesting to understand how it is true...

Comment: Well, in the sense that in the case you're discussing, you have a Harnack inequality, so it must be true, but from your comment above this looks like circular reasoning. It may help for you to state directly what tools you're assuming.

Comment: @RayYang I probably shouldn't have extracted just this bit from the proof, you are right!
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160140329/pdf
page 586, to me, formula (4.5) does not seem to follow from what has been proven before... Not sure if it is obvious and I am missing something. I "fixed" the proof  playing around with the side lenght of the cubes considered. Still wondering what Moser meant there though!